# How to config htaccess for zend framework 2 use sub folder in domain

Tags: php, .htaccess, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I have a sub folder domain like:

```
/domain.com
    L service
        L application
            L ...
        L library
        L public
            L index.php
            L .htaccess
```

And my `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteBase /service  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d  
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]  
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

When I run domain

http://domain.com/service,

it auto redirect to

http://domain.com/service/public.

But I want it not use `/public` folder. How to fix it

Answer (score 0):

public
   L index.php
   L .htaccess

Put both files outside of public folder and delete public folder.
After that open index.php file and replace path

|| define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(**FILE**) . '/../application'));

to

|| define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(**FILE**) . '/application'));

give path of your application folder